# Ipad and Iphone input focus issue

Tags: iphone, html, ipad, tablet

i have an jquery based website its works fine on every browser of pc and table but it isnt working on ipad i can not directly click on input field.
       http://horizontech.biz/deviehl/index_english.html#sthash.2NOCYUFZ.wWGEy5Bq.dpbs

Answer (score 0):

Focus is not possible in ipad( Mobile Safari ).